# Custom Combo box height issue in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight-4.0, custom-controls, silverlight-5.0

In my Custom control, i have issue with drop down menu height. If Combo box items are more, I want scroll mouse many times because of small height of Drop down menu. I want to increase the height of Drop down menu.

FYI - I have generate Custom Control using Generic.xaml file and behavior's of the control are defined in TextBox.cs file (inherited from the Text Box Class).

Thank You..!!

Comment: i think you should use AutoCompletebox instade of Combobox

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MaxDropDownHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.maxdropdownheight%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Property of your ComboBox to set the desired maximum height you want for it, when unfolded that is.